# Does $f \mid f(x^{p_1}), f(x^{p_2}) \implies f \mid f(x^{p_1 p_2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

**Hypothesis:**

1. Let $p$ be a prime positive integer.
2. $f = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_nx^n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
3. Suppose that $f \mid f(x^{p_1})$ and $f \mid f(x^{p_2}) \in  \mathbb{Z}[x]$

**Question:** Does $f \mid f(x^{p_1 p_2})$?

Comment: $f(x^{p_2})|f(x^{p_1p_2})$

Comment: Why does that hold?

Comment: I made an attempt to show that lemma in this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611110/showing-fxp-1-mid-fxp-1-p-2-given-that-fx-mid-fxp-1-fx