# Showing $f(x^{p_1}) \mid f(x^{p_1 p_2})$ Given that $f(x) \mid f(x^{p_1}), f(x^{p_2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

**Hypothesis:** Let $f = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_nx^n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Suppose $f(x) \mid f(x^{p_1})$ and $f \mid f(x^{p_2})$ for $p_1$ and $p_2$  two positive prime integers.

**Goal:** Show that $f(x^{p_1}) \mid f(x^{p_1 p_2})$.

**Attempt:**

1. We have the following identities:

$$f(x^{p_1}) = a_0 + a_1x^{p_1} + \ldots + a_nx^{p_1 n}$$

$$f(x^{p_2}) = a_0 + a_1x^{p_2} + \ldots + a_nx^{p_2 n}$$

$$f(x^{p_1 p_2}) = a_0 + a_1x^{p_1 p_2} + \ldots + a_nx^{p_1 p_2 n}$$

1. Since $f(x) \mid f(x^{p_1})$, we have that $f(x^{p_1}) = f(x) h(x)$ for some $h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
2. It seems like $f(x)h(x^{p_2})$ could be equal to $f(x^{p_1 p_2})$.

Is this true, and if so, how to go about showing it?

**EDIT:** My attempt is probably the wrong way of going about it since $f(x^{p_2})h(x^{p_2}) = f(x^{p_1 p_2})$ means that $f(x)h(x^{p_2})$ on its own is very unlikely to be equal to $f(x^{p_1 p_2})$.

Answer (score 2):

First we ensure that if for any two polynomials $g_1(x),g_2(x)$  we have $g_1(x) \mid g_2(x)$, then we also know $g_1(x^p) \mid g_2(x^p)$ (e.g. because $x \mapsto x^p$ is an homomorphism of rings.)

So by mapping $x \mapsto x^{p_1}$ we have $$f(x) \mid f(x^{p_2}) \Rightarrow f(x^{p_1}) \mid f((x^{p_1})^{p_2})=f(x^{p_1 p_2}).$$

I am not sure, if you are interested, but

Fun fact 1) we haven't used the fact, that $p_1$, $p_2$ are prime.

Fun fact 2) if $f(x) \mid f(x^p)$, then all complex roots of $f$ are unit roots, thus $f$ divides $x^n-1$ for some n.

Comment: $x\mapsto x^p$ is rather an *endomorphism* of rings in general.

Comment: Oops! Looks like I dealt with too many isomorphisms today... Thanks!